# Cannot assign to "" in "self" - Working with Tuples in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have to classes: `FirstViewController` and `PlanGenerator`.

`PlanGenerator` has a method called `getPlanForIndex (day:Int) -> ([PlanElement], [PlanElement])?`. It is returning two different Arrays, both containing Object of `Plan Element`.

```
getPlanForIndex (day:Int) -> ([PlanElement], [PlanElement])? {

    // Do some work and fill arrays
    return (firstArray, secondArray)
}
```

In the `FirstViewController` I've created two Properties:

```
let plan:[PlanElement] = [PlanElement]()
let planGen:PlanGenerator = PlanGenerator()
```

`FirstViewController`has a method called:

```
func prepareView () {

    plan = planGen.getPlanForIndex(dayIndex)    
}
```

But when I want to call this, I get the error message:
`Cannot assign to 'plan' in 'self'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `plan` member is a constant (declared with `let`), and you're assigning to it outside of `init`. If you want to assign to it after initialization, it needs to be declared with `var`.

Also, your `getPlanForIndex` returns a tuple, and you're assigning it to a member of singular (not tuple) type. If you want to assign one part of a tuple only, do it like this:

```
    (plan, _) = planGen.getPlanForIndex(dayIndex)
```

That assigns a tuple to a tuple, satisfying the compiler, but discards the second element.

If you instead want `plan` to be a tuple, you'll have to declare and initialize it as such. Looks from the comments like you figured out a way to do that, but here's a way with minimal typing (in either sense of the word):

```
var plan: ([PlanElement], [PlanElement]) = ([], [])
```

(Once you've declared the type of array, `[]` is understood to be an empty array of that type. Just `var plan = ([], [])` leaves the type ambiguous.)

Comment: Ok, so how do I assign both arrays to `plan`? I think I should do something like this in the declaration: `var plan:([PlanElement], [PlanElement]) = ` but what to do now?

Comment: Really that depends on what you plan to use `plan` for and when. If you want it to hold a tuple of two arrays, and don't plan on using it before your `prepareView` method runs, you could initialize it with a tuple of two empty arrays `([], [])`. Or make it an optional so you can more strictly keep track of whether you've initialized it.

Comment: Yes I don't use it before `prepareView`. But if I do it like that `var plan = ([], [])`, I get an error message in the line `plan = planGen.getPlanForIndex(dayIndex)` that's saying `Cannot express tuple conversion '([PlanElement], [PlanElement])' to '(NSArray, NSArray)'`. So I finally fixed it like this: `var plan:([PlanElement], [PlanElement]) = ([PlanElement](), [PlanElement]())`